# Update SharePoint Default Alternate Access Mapping Programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, api, powershell, alternate-access-mappings

I'm enabling HTTPS on my IIS server where I have SharePoint Services 3.0 installed and I'd like to programatically update the default alternate access mappings for a single web application and my central administration instance (both on the same machine). Here's the code I have so far (Powershell), it adds a mapping for HTTPS but I get and error when trying to remove the original one.

Here's my code:

```
[void][system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Sharepoint")

$SPWebServiceCollection = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebServiceCollection ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local)

    foreach ($SPWebService in $SPWebServiceCollection) {

        foreach ($webApplication in $SPWebService.WebApplications) {
    
            Write-Host ('Updating {0}' -f $webApplication.Name)

            foreach ($alternateUrl in $webApplication.AlternateUrls) {
        
                $incomingUrl = [System.URI] $alternateUrl.IncomingUrl
        
                $newURL = 'https://{0}{1}' -f  $incomingUrl.Authority, $incomingUrl.PathAndQuery
        
                $newAltURL = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAlternateUrl ($newURL, $alternateUrl.UrlZone)
        
                $webApplication.AlternateUrls.Add($newAltURL)
                    
                $webApplication.AlternateUrls.Update($true)

                $webApplication.AlternateUrls.Remove($alternateUrl) #Throws Exception

                $webApplication.AlternateUrls.Update($true)
           }
        }
    }
```

Here is the error I get when I try to remove the original:

> Exception calling "Remove" with "1" argument(s): "An object in the SharePoint administrative framework, "SPAlternateUrlCollection Name=SharePoint - 1000 Parent=SPFarm Name=SharePoint_Config_8ddd3701-a332-4e79-98e4-fa11c1b6c17c", could not be deleted because other objects depend on it.  Update all of these dependants to point to null or different objects and retry this operation.  The dependant objects are as follows:
>
> SPWebApplication Name=SharePoint - 1000 Parent=SPWebService

However, i'm not sure how to do what the exception suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's another method for the exiting default entry that I overlooked:

```
$webApplication.AlternateUrls.SetResponseUrl($newAltURL)


[void][system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Sharepoint")

$SPWebServiceCollection = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebServiceCollection ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local)

foreach ($SPWebService in $SPWebServiceCollection) {

    foreach ($webApplication in $SPWebService.WebApplications) {

        Write-Host ('Updating {0}' -f $webApplication.Name)

        foreach ($alternateUrl in $webApplication.AlternateUrls) {

            $incomingUrl = [System.URI] $alternateUrl.IncomingUrl

            $newURL = 'https://{0}{1}' -f  $incomingUrl.Authority, $incomingUrl.PathAndQuery

            $newAltURL = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAlternateUrl ($newURL, $alternateUrl.UrlZone)

            $webApplication.AlternateUrls.SetResponseUrl($newAltURL)

            $webApplication.AlternateUrls.Update($true)
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah... it looks like you are trying to remove the URL the Webservice is using...